# Can a future president undo Trump's TikTok ban or is it outside of their control?

Tags: united-states, president, law, executive-order

Can a future president undo Trump's TikTok ban, or would it be outside of their control? I am wondering, if Trump's executive order against TikTok passes, whether his successor (be it Biden, or someone else) would be able to reverse it. If so, how would the process of undoing this particular executive order proceed?

Comment: A better question might be why the order is legal at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

An executive order can be undone simply by issuing another executive order reversing the first.

Comment: No.  The [Supreme Court just recently ruled](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/19pdf/18-587_5ifl.pdf) that President Trump could not "simply [issue] another executive order" to repeal President Obama's DACA executive order and had to follow a substantive process.

Comment: @just me,  please write an answer.

Comment: @JustMe I am not sure you can count the supreme court acting here as saying future presidents don't have the ability to undo an executive order. There have been many other cases in the Trump presidency where he has undone an executive order that was put in place by Obama. This was a single case where his actions where objected to and the supreme court upheld that objection. In order for the court to also stop a reversal of the TikTok ban someone would have to object to it and file a lawsuit after it is put in place. This is ignoring the question that the ban may fall to lawsuits before that.

Comment: @JustMe Could you clarify why you think that ruling is relevant here? Sure, executive orders need to follow the law, but I see no reason why the executive order proposed by Joe C would be in any way illegal, so you should clarify your reasoning if you're going to challenge his answer. Specifically, if you mean that Trump's executive order was illegal because repealing earlier executive orders is always (or often) illegal, that would be wrong as that's not what the Supreme Court ruled at all.